# Does Ignite support transactions initiated using IgniteCache.query() method?

Tags: java, ignite

Ignite's documentation https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-transactions mentions that transactions are supported for SQL queries. But there are two ways to run a SQL query (at least, in Java):

- Using JDBC: this seems supported, the corresponding queries are mentioned in the docs https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/transactions
- Using `IgniteCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(...))`

Does this second mode support transactions initiated with `Ignite.transactions().txStart()`? I mean, do queries initiated using this method participate in transactions initiated with `Ignite.transactions().txStart()`?

Comment: If you need transactions in Ignite, you should use the key-value API rather than SQL. `TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT` isn't ready for real-world use.

Comment: @StephenDarlington do I understand correctly that indexes are only supported via SQL? And so, if I need both indexes and transactions, I'd have to give up on Ignite?

Comment: Most people can use a combination of APIs, for example finding the keys using SQL and then getting/putting using the key-value API.